# How to convert SMILE into TEXT (android)

Tags: android

I have Android 4.4, and someone messaged me unknown smile (to be true, most of smiles are strange to me), and I dont know which combination was used for that smile,

```
:* :P or i something other i dont know
```

how can i know, which combination was used? Have I to type every combination manually to find that?

Comment: Maybe you meant to post this question in [android.se] by mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You can find here the list (and search using <kbd>ctrl+f</kbd> and then paste the emojii):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_emoticons

Comment: but I cant find that smile int he list, because ANdroid has specific ANDRO-SMILES.

Comment: It's the same smiles they just look different, here is the full list :)   http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html